# Doing a Loading Bar in C

Tags: c

I want to use this loading bar but I want to print the content in two separated lines.
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
   #include <string.h>

    int main (){
        for (float i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
            printf("\r DOING THIS thing ... In progress  %.2f%%", i/100);
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

This gives me the result in terminal like this:
DOING THIS thing ... In progress  99.99%

What I want is this:

DOING THIS thing ...
In progress  99.99%

I tried `\n` but this just creates a new line for each iteration of the loop.
Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Well... Why don't you just print "DOING THIS thing" before the loop then?

Comment: Just print the first line once before the loop, then output the `"\rIn progress ..."` message inside the loop. If you need to change the contents of the first line, you're out of luck without ANSI terminal codes or similar. Or just use _ncurses_ library.

Comment: Can you use [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) library?

Comment: If you have [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) available in your terminal, try `printf("\x1b[13;9HDOING THIS thing ...\x1b[14;9HIn progress  %.2f%%", i/100);`

Comment: Thank you for your comments but i cant just print "DOING THIS thing" before the loop  because its supposed to change as the progress changes too.

Answer (score 1):

This may do the trick:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main () {
    printf("\r DOING THIS thing ...\n");
    printf("In progress 00.00%%");
    for (float i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
       printf("\b\b\b\b\b");
       printf("%2.2f%%", i/100);
       fflush(stdout);
       sleep(1);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

`\b` represents the backspace.